Python sigwait on SIGCHLD - does not return on child termination
I am trying to wait in python until either

some given signal fires (the signal itself can be ignored)
a child process exits

There is a function os.sigwait that seems to fit this purpose, but I cannot get it to return on a forked child process exit by calling os.sigwait({signal.SIGCHLD}) - this ends in a deadlock.
What I tried:
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import signal
import os
import time

if __name__ == '__main__':
    pid = None  # initial value

    try:
        pid = os.fork() # method is available only on UNIX platforms

        if pid != 0:  # parent
            # Wait for child exit or SIGINT
            # (should also work for signals other than SIGINT)
            signal.sigwait({signal.SIGCHLD, signal.SIGINT})
            print("Got signal")
            # never reaching this statement by child exit

        else:  # child
            time.sleep(3)

    finally:
        if pid is None: # fork failed
            pass
        elif pid == 0:
            print("\nChild cleaning up")
        else:
            print("\nParent cleaning up")


Are you on Windows? In that case, SIGCHLD is not raised, try some other approach, such as os.waitpid().

I am on ubuntu 22.04

What happens if you pthread_sigmask(SIG_BLOCK, {SIGCHLD, SIGINT}) before the call to sigwait?  The behavior of sigwait is undefined unless the desired signals are blocked at the time of the call.

Why aren't you using a higher-level interface like the subprocess module?

thank you @pilcrow, pthread_sigmask(SIG_BLOCK, {SIGCHLD, SIGINT}) did the work. My locally installed man page misses the section about this undefined behavior.
